# pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN not registering

Tags: python, events, pygame, mouse

For some reason I can't get `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` to register on `pygame.event.get()`.

```py
events_list = pygame.event.get()
for event in events_list:
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_i:
            menu_close = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print(event.button)
```

While `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` returns when I press any button, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong with the code highlighted above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). In your code `event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` is evaluated only, if `event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN` is `True`. That's impossible, since `event.type` can't have 2 states at once.

Instead of:

> ```py
> if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
>     if event.key == pygame.K_i:
>         menu_close = True
>     if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
>         print(event.button)
> ```

It has to be:

```py
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_i:
        menu_close = True
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    print(event.button)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Such a simple fix. It was driving me crazy! =)